# How to insert values using column name with space?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I want to insert value from PostgreSQL to SQLite. Value is column name with space. My code:

```
def copy_videos():
    create_table_videos()    
    query1 = run_query("SELECT * FROM videos")
    with local_engine.connect() as conn:
        query2 = f"INSERT INTO videos values (:video_id, :title, \":length (min)\" , :category_id, :created_at)"
        conn.execute(text(query2), query1)
        query = "SELECT * FROM videos as videos"
        rows = conn.execute(text(query))
        # conn.commit()
        for x in rows.all():
            return(x['videos'])
print(copy_videos())
```

The output :

> sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind
> parameter 'length' [SQL: INSERT INTO videos values (?, ?, "? (min)" ,
> ?, ?)] [parameters: [{'video_id':
> '132f767c-2507-4de8-8609-0268c7c2c651', 'title': 'fashion basket bald
> oval glyph', 'length (min)': 41.9313587667618, 'category_id': 2.0, ...
> (246953 characters truncated) ...  Eccles burnish mind coupe', 'length
> (min)': 55.7423979070126, 'category_id': 15.0, 'created_at':
> datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 19, 18, 45, 40, 980416)}]]

Comment: `return` in the `for` loop will end the loop on the first iteration, it won't return all the rows. Use `return [x['videos'] for x in rows.all()]` to return all the videos.

Comment: I'm not sure you can have a space in a placeholder. I don't see anything about it in the sqlalchemy documentation.

Comment: If you think that using placeholder names that that are the same as the column names will automatically "match up" the parameter values with the columns in the table then you are mistaken. `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (:param_x, :param_y)` will only work if the table is defined with column "x" followed by column "y". It won't work as you expect if the table is defined with column "y" followed by column "x". That's one of the reasons why `INSERT INTO table_name VALUES …` (without an explicit list of column names) is not recommended; use `INSERT INTO table_name (x, y) VALUES …` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its not recommended to have columns like that.
Best solution: rename column to length_min (or something like that)

If you can't do that, I'd recommend the following:

1. Select using double quotes and then rename using the `as` keyword in your query to postgres:

   `query1 = run_query('select video_id, title, "length (min)" as length_min, category_id, created_at from videos')`
2. Change your query2 to:

   `query2 = "INSERT INTO videos (video_id, title, length_min , category_id, created_at) values (:video_id, :title, :length_min , :category_id, :created_at)"`